# Ajax: Javascript cannot appear html code from Server Response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm currently trying to create a search engine in a site using ajax. I want the results to appear in my primary page in a:

```
<div id="searchResults"></div>
```

I also want each result to be like this:

```
<div id='product_box'>
   <h2 style='color: blue'>Result 1</h2>
   <b style='text-decoration: underline'>Price:</b> <b style='color: red'> 500 Euros</b><br><br>
   <b style='text-decoration: underline'>Description:</b> <b style='font-style: italic'>mpla mpla mpla</b>      
</div>;
```

Additionally, I tried to create the server response as a ResponseText and not a ResponseXML. However, I want the server to pass in my page another two values. For this reason, I created the code below:

```
<?php
/*---Interaction with the database---*/
$response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$response .= '<response>';
$response .= '<numOfResults>' . $numOfProducts . '</numOfResults>';
$response .= '<maxNumOfProducts>' . $maxNumOfProducts . '</maxNumOfProducts>';

$str = "";

while ($productsOfTheSearch = mysqli_fetch_array($query_select_products))
{
    $product_id = $productsOfTheSearch['product_id'];
    $product_title = $productsOfTheSearch['product_title'];
    $product_price = $productsOfTheSearch['product_price'];
    $product_desc = $productsOfTheSearch['product_desc'];
    
    $str .= "
        <div id='product_box'>
   <h2 style='color: blue'>$product_title</h2>
   <b style='text-decoration: underline'>Price:</b> <b style='color: red'> $product_price Euros</b><br><br>
   <b style='text-decoration: underline'>Description:</b> <b style='font-style: italic'>$product_desc</b>       
        </div>; 
        ";
}

$response .= '<results>' . $str . '</results>';

$response .= '</response>'; 
$response .= '</xml>';  

echo $response;

?>
```

My respective js file:

```
//Preparation functions... xmlHttp is the object from the XMLHttpRequest().
function handleServerResponse()
{
   if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
   {
        response = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText,'text/xml');
        
        x = response.getElementsByTagName("numOfResults");
        numOfResults = x[0].firstChild.data;
        x = response.getElementsByTagName("maxNumOfProducts");
        maxNumOfProducts = x[0].firstChild.data;

        //things with numOfResults and maxNumOfProducts.
        //These work fine!!!

        x = response.getElementsByTagName("results");
        
        document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = x[0].firstChild.data
        
        setTimeout('searchFunction()', 200);
   }
}
```

The text inside the tags -results- passes normally in my page but it is not able to appear. On the contrary, it appears the word "undefined".

Could someone help me with this problem? Perhaps, is there any easier way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I see error here `str = "";` should be `$str = "";`. Not sure if it will fix your issue, but it will if your query is not returning any rows.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. I didn't copy that right. In my code, there is dollar sign.

Comment: What is the `data` property supposed to be? I'd try appending `x[0].firstChild` instead